# Find Kth digit number after n changes

Tags: java, bit

There is a changing rule that, 0 -> 01, 1 -> 10. For example, after the change, 10 is 1001.

Assume that the input is 0, after n changes of such rule, what is the Kth digit?

I can only come with the brutal solution, which is as followings. However I believe there exist better solutions, can anyone come up with some new ideas?

```
public char lalala(int n, int k) {
    String str = "0";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
            if (str.charAt(j) == '0') {
                sb.append("01");
            } else {
                sb.append("10");
            }
        }
        str = sb.toString();
    }
    return str.charAt(k);
}
```

Comment: What *rule* are you implementing?

Comment: Sorry, forget to add it. There is a changing rule that, 0 -> 01, 1 -> 10. For example, after the change, 10 is 1001.

Comment: your program is incorrect: (1) k-th number in your program is (k-1)-th . (2) Use StringBuilder to append characters in your way is incorrect, use replacing.

Comment: @dovy (2) OP code is correct. In each iteration new StringBuilder is created so we don't add new characters to existing string, but we are actually creating new string which will replace old values with new ones. Using `replace` on original string will cause problems because we will first replace `0` with `01`, but then when we will try to replace `1` with `10` we will also replace newly added `1` (the one from replacing `0`), which is not what we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your generated string will look like

```
0110100110010110....
```

Now lets write this numbers vertically and lets print binary representation of position of each digit

```
value|position -> position binary
-----+---------------------------
0    | 0       -> 0000
1    | 1       -> 0001
1    | 2       -> 0010
0    | 3       -> 0011
1    | 4       -> 0100
0    | 5       -> 0101
0    | 6       -> 0110
1    | 7       -> 0111
.      .          ....
.      .          ....
```

If you take closer look you will see that:

- if number of `1` in binary representation of `position` is even `value` is `0`
- if number of `1` in binary representation of `position` is odd `value` is `1`

which means that

`0001`, `0010`, `0100`, `0111` contains odd number of `1` *value* will be `1`.

In other words `value` is equal of *`number of ones` modulo `2`*.

Using this fact you can create code which will convert your `n` to string representing its binary form, sum all ones, and check if it is odd or even.

Code converting `n` to `value` can look like this

```
public static int value(int n) {
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    return binary.chars().map(e -> e == '1' ? 1 : 0).sum() % 2;
}
```

(little longer version if you are not familiar with streams introduced in Java 8)

```
public static int value(Integer n) {
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    int count = 0;
    for (char ch : binary.toCharArray())
        if (ch == '1') count ++;
    return count % 2;
}
```

and when you use it like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    System.out.print(value(i));
```

you will get as output `01101001100101101001` which seems correct.